# pin_ptr & PtrToStringChars vs. StringToHGlobalAnsi: Why does PtrToStringChars var loose its value?

Tags: string, c++-cli, marshalling, wchar-t, pin-ptr

I am using C++/CLI and I want to call the function `WNetAddConnection2` from Windows Networking.
*First, I know that C++/CLI is not the language of choice for my work, but I have no possibility to change that right now and e.g. use C# instead.*

The problem now is, that this function takes wchar_t*, so I need to convert System::String^ to wchar_t*.
Solution 1): use `pin_ptr` and `PtrToSTringChars` from `vcclr.h`
Solution 2): use `StringToHGlobalUni`. (The title mentions `StringHToGlobalAnsi` because more people are searching for that so they might find this post and it's answers faster).

I have found out that both solutions work. But #1 does not really. I have put the WNet-functions into a ref class `CWNetShare` with following constructor:

```
CWNetShare::CWNetShare (String^ i_sLocalDrive, ...) {
  pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wszTemp;
  wszTemp = PtrToStringChars(i_sLocalDrive);
  m_wszLocalDrive = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wszTemp);
```

where `m_wszLocalDrive` is a private `CWNetShare` member of type `wchar_t*`.

The real problem: while calling the constructor by `m_oWNetShare = gcnew CWNetShare` from a Winform class constructor (I know, C++/CLI and Winforms...), everything seems fine. The string `i_sLocalDrive` and others are converted and assigned correctly. But when accessing `m_oWNetShare` later, the values in all m_wsz... variables are lost. It looks like the object was moved around by the GC.
Therefore I have made a test:

```
ref class CManaged {
public:
  wchar_t* m_wszNothing;
  wchar_t* m_wszPinned;
  wchar_t* m_wszMarshal;
  System::String^ m_sTest;

  CManaged ()
  {
    m_sTest = "Hello";
    m_wszNothing = L"Test";

    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wszTemp;
    wszTemp = PtrToStringChars(m_sTest);
    m_wszPinned = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wszTemp);
    m_wszMarshal = static_cast<wchar_t*>(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni (m_sTest).ToPointer());
  }
};
```

Again a winform with `m_oManaged = gcnew CManaged;` in its constructor. When accessing m_oManaged later, then if m_oManaged was not moved, `m_wszPinned` is ok.
[image]
But after GCing, it's showing nonsense. BUT m_wsznothing keeps it's value, so it's not a problem of `wchar_t*`, but of the pin_ptr somehow. The address of `m_oManaged` has changed, but the address of `m_wszPinned` is the same, so why is the value lost then?
[image]

What is going wrong here?
Does pin_ptr and PtrToSTringChars have a use at all then?

I'm using marshalling now, which works.

Comment: Remember to call `FreeHGlobal()` on the `IntPtr` that's returned from `StringToHGlobalUni()` as documented in "[How to: Convert System::String to Standard String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623.aspx)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PtrToStringChars is literally that: a pointer to the character array that the String^ holds internally.

When you're saving that pointer, it's a pointer to a managed object that the garbage collector is allowed to move. You're only guaranteed that it won't move for as long as the pin_ptr exists, which you're not keeping around. As soon as the pin_ptr no longer exists, the garbage collector is free to move the managed object around, and your pointer now points at some other object, somewhere in the managed heap.

Use PtrToStringChars if you're going to call an unmanaged function, and you don't need the string to persist beyond that one API call (and the unmanaged function doesn't keep a reference to the string). Use StringToHGlobalUni if you need to keep the unmanaged string around long-term.

Comment: Don't use `StringToHGlobalUni` ever.  It's not exception-safe, its name is misleading, and it is inefficient.  If you need to keep a native copy of the string around, keep a `std::wstring`, either by passing the result of `PtrToStringChars()` to the `wstring` constructor, or using `marshal_as<std::wstring>()`